# android dialog transparant

Tags: android, dialog, transparency

It is a simple stupid question, but i cant find any info on the web.
I have an android app with a custom dialog. The dialog has the default grey 1px border. But it also has a black border around that grey line.

I want to remove the black part.

the dialog is made in xml and i call:
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.xxxxx);

as soon as i do that the black border is there. However the xml has not a background color set. also a transparant color in the xml doesn't helps.

if i do not call setcontentview. then a small dialog appears but without a strange border.

[image: example of dialog]

Comment: can you post that image please ? so we can see it and try to resolve your problem .

Comment: here is the image. Do you understand the black part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found.
I made a new layoutparameter object. I put the heigth en width in it. and put the paramters in the dialog.
But i should get the layoutparameters from the dialogobject. and changed the heigt and width in there.

I used: 
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

But needed to use:
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

so problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Try using a transparent theme for your popup

```
 new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: this removes the complete border. Not only the black part but also the grey border...